# Django - Getting initial value before altering user input in generic UpdateView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Say for example I have a model that stores Fruits as Apples, Bananas and Oranges inside a basket (every separate instance is going to be a basket).

```
class Project(models.Model):

  apples = models.DecimalField('Apples!', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)

  oranges = models.DecimalField('Oranges!', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)

  bananas = models.DecimalField('Bananas!', decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

Use case:

There are A, B and C Apples, Oranges and Bananas in the database in separate baskets.
User presses on separate basket to update, gets his apples, oranges and bananas fields.
He inputs X amount of Apples, Y amount of Oranges and Z amount of Bananas in the database.

There are now A+X apples, Y+B oranges and C+Z bananas. In other words, instead of just updating the amount of fruit, user simply adds to them (without subtracting for the moment)

**The problem is**, when trying to override the save() method in forms.py, I cannot seem to properly access the current instance of the basket and, therefore, the correct amount of currently-placed fruit in the basket. Updating with my programmatic additions works, but I cannot get the initial values. How do I do it?

```
class BasketForm(ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = Basket
    fields = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'UPDATE'))


def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.actual_design = self.cleaned_data.get('actual_design') // this didnt work
    current_project = self.instance.actual_design // this didnt work
    print(self.instance.apples) // returns already inputted X amount of apples

    add = super(BasketForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if commit:
        add.save()
    return add
```

Comment: That's *not* the responsibility of the form usually, but that of the view: you pass the instance as parameter to the form. I find it rather weird that you use `Decimal`s here instead of `Integer`s.

Comment: It was a requirement for my current task. So you're saying I've got more luck trying this out in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ModelForm` has an attribute on it called `initial`. This will hold the initial values of the form, the values before the field changed.

It is essentially a dictionary, keys being the model field names and values being their initial values (assuming you initialized the form with the instance correctly). You can use this to hook on to the original values pre-update.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    self.apples += self.initial['apples'] 
    ...
```

Ideally, this kind of magic should be avoided; try to make the FE/API call send the correct value; or write business logic before it is passed to the ModelForm

Comment: My hero! This what I was looking for!

Comment: Happy to help; although this is a bit of *black magic* -> not the ideal solution. Please read Willem's comment :)